# Configure different eslint rules for a set of paths

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, eslint

I want a easy way to run a different set of rules in all my `__tests__` paths so I don't need to use inline config in each file like this

```
// eslint-env jasmin:true
/*
  eslint
    max-nested-callbacks: 0,
    no-unused-expressions:0,
    prefer-arrow-callback:0,
    func-names: 0,
    max-len: [2 , 150]
*/
```

Creating a .eslintrc file in each `__tests__` is basically the same, so, it's no an option since there's a lot of tests along my app.

Answer (score 6):

ESLint supports multiple configuration files. The closest config file to the code file takes highest priority. So you can create a separate `.eslintrc` file in your tests directory with the set of rules that apply to your tests, and another one for your code. ESLint will automatically pick them up as it lints.
If you don't want to recreate the same file over and over, you can use `extend` functionality of config files, and extend the same file located at the root directory. You will still have to create a config file per directory, but it will only contain one statement.

The only other way to do what you are looking for is to run ESLint twice, ones for your code, and ones for all of your tests. You can use `-c` CLI argument to pass correct config for each run.

Comment: ESLint version 4.0.1 now includes ability to override configurations based on the globs. So you can now do different configuration for different files, based on the pattern.

Answer (score 5):

[ESlint has the option](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns) to `override` the base configuration.  It accepts an `array` so you can add as many overrides as you like.

I used this in one of my recent configurations:

```json
{
  /*...*/
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["**/*.fixture.tsx"],
      "rules": {
        "no-console": "off"
      }
    }
  ]
 /*...*/
}
```